# Tweaking MySQL 5.7: 2013 lost connection error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I recently upgraded a light-duty (running just a handful of smallish WordPress sites at the moment) MAMP server (first "M" is for "Mac", it's not the MAMP package install but individually installed source components via MacPorts) to PHP7 and MySQL 5.7, and though it's mostly been smooth I'm experiencing intermittent instances where the web site errors while trying to connect to the db.  The same sites worked fine on PHP5.3 with MySQL 5.5.

I get similar problems when accessing MySQL via commandline (Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102 when trying to connect), so I'm pretty sure it's not primarily a PHP7 problem.

I've updated various tables (changing default dates from 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, for instance) and tried tweaking some settings, but I'm a bit new at that level of detail.  I've searched a fair bit and haven't come up with a clear path forward. I'm hoping one of you can look at the current variable settings below and quickly see what's amiss.

Thanks in advance!

```
auto_increment_increment     1
auto_increment_offset        1
autocommit     ON
automatic_sp_privileges      ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade       OFF
back_log       100
basedir        /opt/local/
big_tables     OFF
bind_address   *
binlog_cache_size            32768
binlog_checksum              CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates    OFF
binlog_error_action          ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format                ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay             0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count    0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery  ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time  0
binlog_order_commits         ON
binlog_row_image             FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events               OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size       32768
block_encryption_mode        aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size      8388608
character_set_client         utf8
character_set_connection     utf8
character_set_database       utf8
character_set_filesystem     binary
character_set_results        utf8
character_set_server         utf8
character_set_system         utf8
character_sets_dir           /opt/local/share/mysql57/charsets/
check_proxy_users            OFF
collation_connection         utf8_general_ci
collation_database           utf8_general_ci
collation_server             utf8_general_ci
completion_type              NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert            AUTO
connect_timeout              10
core_file      OFF
datadir        /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/
date_format    %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format              %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin              mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime    0
default_storage_engine       InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine   InnoDB
default_week_format          0
delay_key_write              ON
delayed_insert_limit         100
delayed_insert_timeout       300
delayed_queue_size           1000
disabled_storage_engines
disconnect_on_expired_password             ON
div_precision_increment      4
end_markers_in_json          OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency     OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit    200
event_scheduler              OFF
expire_logs_days             0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp            OFF
flush          OFF
flush_time     0
foreign_key_checks           ON
ft_boolean_syntax            + -><()~*:""&
ft_max_word_len              84
ft_min_word_len              4
ft_query_expansion_limit     20
ft_stopword_file             (built-in)
general_log    OFF
general_log_file             /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/254.log
group_concat_max_len         1024
gtid_executed
gtid_executed_compression_period           1000
gtid_mode      OFF
gtid_owned
gtid_purged
have_compress                YES
have_crypt     YES
have_dynamic_loading         YES
have_geometry                YES
have_openssl   YES
have_profiling               YES
have_query_cache             YES
have_rtree_keys              YES
have_ssl       YES
have_statement_timeout       YES
have_symlink   YES
host_cache_size              378
hostname       254.domain.com
ignore_builtin_innodb        OFF
ignore_db_dirs
init_connect
init_file
init_slave
innodb_adaptive_flushing     ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm               10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index   ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts           8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay            150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval              5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock   OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog     OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl        OFF
innodb_api_trx_level         0
innodb_autoextend_increment  64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode     1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size              134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown        ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct  25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename  ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances               1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort              OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup         ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size      268435456
innodb_change_buffer_max_size              25
innodb_change_buffering      all
innodb_checksum_algorithm    crc32
innodb_checksums             ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled               OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency    0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct   5
innodb_compression_level     6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max             50
innodb_concurrency_tickets   5000
innodb_data_file_path        ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir
innodb_deadlock_detect       ON
innodb_default_row_format    dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache             OFF
innodb_doublewrite           ON
innodb_fast_shutdown         1
innodb_file_format           Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check     ON
innodb_file_format_max       Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table        ON
innodb_fill_factor           100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit             1
innodb_flush_method
innodb_flush_neighbors       1
innodb_flush_sync            ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops    30
innodb_force_load_corrupted  OFF
innodb_force_recovery        0
innodb_ft_aux_table
innodb_ft_cache_size         8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print  OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword    ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size     84
innodb_ft_min_token_size     3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize  2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit               2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree    2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size   640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
innodb_io_capacity           200
innodb_io_capacity_max       2000
innodb_large_prefix          ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout     50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog             OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size       16777216
innodb_log_checksums         ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages  ON
innodb_log_file_size         67108864
innodb_log_files_in_group    2
innodb_log_group_home_dir    ./
innodb_log_write_ahead_size  8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth        1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct   75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm             0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag         0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay   0
innodb_max_undo_log_size     1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable
innodb_monitor_enable
innodb_monitor_reset
innodb_monitor_reset_all
innodb_old_blocks_pct        37
innodb_old_blocks_time       1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size           134217728
innodb_open_files            2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only              OFF
innodb_page_cleaners         1
innodb_page_size             16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks   OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size      300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency       128
innodb_purge_threads         4
innodb_random_read_ahead     OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold  56
innodb_read_io_threads       4
innodb_read_only             OFF
innodb_replication_delay     0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout   OFF
innodb_rollback_segments     128
innodb_sort_buffer_size      1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay       6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc     ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked         OFF
innodb_stats_method          nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata     OFF
innodb_stats_persistent      ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages       20
innodb_stats_sample_pages    8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages        8
innodb_status_output         OFF
innodb_status_output_locks   OFF
innodb_strict_mode           ON
innodb_support_xa            ON
innodb_sync_array_size       1
innodb_sync_spin_loops       30
innodb_table_locks           ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path   ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency    0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay    10000
innodb_tmpdir
innodb_undo_directory        ./
innodb_undo_log_truncate     OFF
innodb_undo_logs             128
innodb_undo_tablespaces      0
innodb_use_native_aio        OFF
innodb_version               5.7.17
innodb_write_io_threads      4
interactive_timeout          28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine           InnoDB
join_buffer_size             262144
keep_files_on_create         OFF
key_buffer_size              8388608
key_cache_age_threshold      300
key_cache_block_size         1024
key_cache_division_limit     100
large_files_support          ON
large_page_size              0
large_pages    OFF
lc_messages    en_US
lc_messages_dir              /opt/local/share/mysql57/
lc_time_names                en_US
license        GPL
local_infile   ON
lock_wait_timeout            31536000
locked_in_memory             OFF
log_bin        OFF
log_bin_basename
log_bin_index
log_bin_trust_function_creators            OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events    OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password      OFF
log_error      stderr
log_error_verbosity          3
log_output     FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes              OFF
log_slave_updates            OFF
log_slow_admin_statements    OFF
log_slow_slave_statements    OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog           ON
log_syslog     OFF
log_syslog_facility          daemon
log_syslog_include_pid       ON
log_syslog_tag
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes     0
log_timestamps               UTC
log_warnings   2
long_query_time              10.000000
low_priority_updates         OFF
lower_case_file_system       ON
lower_case_table_names       2
master_info_repository       FILE
master_verify_checksum       OFF
max_allowed_packet           4194304
max_binlog_cache_size        18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size              1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors           100
max_connections              250
max_delayed_threads          20
max_digest_length            1024
max_error_count              64
max_execution_time           0
max_heap_table_size          33554432
max_insert_delayed_threads   20
max_join_size                18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data     1024
max_points_in_geometry       65536
max_prepared_stmt_count      16382
max_relay_log_size           0
max_seeks_for_key            18446744073709551615
max_sort_length              1024
max_sp_recursion_depth       0
max_tmp_tables               32
max_user_connections         0
max_write_lock_count         18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size    1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances              8
min_examined_row_limit       0
multi_range_count            256
myisam_data_pointer_size     6
myisam_max_sort_file_size    9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size             18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options       OFF
myisam_repair_threads        1
myisam_sort_buffer_size      8388608
myisam_stats_method          nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap              OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users          OFF
net_buffer_length            16384
net_read_timeout             30
net_retry_count              10
net_write_timeout            60
new            OFF
ngram_token_size             2
offline_mode   OFF
old            OFF
old_alter_table              OFF
old_passwords                0
open_files_limit             5000
optimizer_prune_level        1
optimizer_search_depth       62
optimizer_switch             index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on
optimizer_trace              enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features     greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit        1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size               16384
optimizer_trace_offset       -1
parser_max_mem_size          18446744073709551615
performance_schema           ON
performance_schema_accounts_size           -1
performance_schema_digests_size            10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size       10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size            10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size        10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size 10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size      10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size        10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size             10
performance_schema_hosts_size              -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes        80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances      -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length       1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes        80
performance_schema_max_file_handles        32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances      -1
performance_schema_max_index_stat          -1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes      320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks      -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes       200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances     -1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances     -1
performance_schema_max_program_instances   -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes      40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes      10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances    -1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length     1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes       150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes   193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack     10
performance_schema_max_table_handles       -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances     -1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat     -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes      50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances    -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size            512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size       -1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size      -1
performance_schema_users_size              -1
pid_file       /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/254.sustainablesources.pid
plugin_dir     /opt/local/lib/mysql57/plugin/
port           0
preload_buffer_size          32768
profiling      OFF
profiling_history_size       15
protocol_version             10
query_alloc_block_size       8192
query_cache_limit            1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit     4096
query_cache_size             1048576
query_cache_type             OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate               OFF
query_prealloc_size          8192
range_alloc_block_size       4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size               8388608
rbr_exec_mode                STRICT
read_buffer_size             131072
read_only      OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size         262144
relay_log
relay_log_basename           /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/254-relay-bin
relay_log_index              /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/254-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file          relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository    FILE
relay_log_purge              ON
relay_log_recovery           OFF
relay_log_space_limit        0
report_host
report_password
report_port    0
report_user
require_secure_transport     OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout       31536000
secure_auth    ON
secure_file_priv             /opt/local/var/db/mysql57-files/
server_id      0
server_id_bits               32
server_uuid    ebdb8ee8-be4c-11e6-8ec5-97f60e5fb56e
session_track_gtids          OFF
session_track_schema         ON
session_track_state_change   OFF
session_track_system_variables             time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info             OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys     ON
sha256_password_private_key_path           private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users  OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path            public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56        OFF
show_old_temporals           OFF
skip_external_locking        ON
skip_name_resolve            ON
skip_networking              ON
skip_show_database           OFF
slave_allow_batching         OFF
slave_checkpoint_group       512
slave_checkpoint_period      300
slave_compressed_protocol    OFF
slave_exec_mode              STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir            /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/
slave_max_allowed_packet     1073741824
slave_net_timeout            60
slave_parallel_type          DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers       0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max  16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order  OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms               TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors            OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum    ON
slave_transaction_retries    10
slave_type_conversions
slow_launch_time             2
slow_query_log               OFF
slow_query_log_file          /opt/local/var/db/mysql57/254-slow.log
socket         /opt/local/var/run/mysql57/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size             262144
sql_auto_is_null             OFF
sql_big_selects              ON
sql_buffer_result            OFF
sql_log_off    OFF
sql_mode       ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes      ON
sql_quote_show_create        ON
sql_safe_updates             OFF
sql_select_limit             18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter       0
sql_warnings   OFF
ssl_ca         ca.pem
ssl_capath
ssl_cert       server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher
ssl_crl
ssl_crlpath
ssl_key        server-key.pem
stored_program_cache         256
super_read_only              OFF
sync_binlog    1
sync_frm       ON
sync_master_info             10000
sync_relay_log               10000
sync_relay_log_info          10000
system_time_zone             CST
table_definition_cache       1400
table_open_cache             2000
table_open_cache_instances   16
thread_cache_size            10
thread_handling              one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack   262144
time_format    %H:%i:%s
time_zone      SYSTEM
tls_version    TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size               33554432
tmpdir         /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/
transaction_alloc_block_size               8192
transaction_prealloc_size    4096
transaction_write_set_extraction           OFF
tx_isolation   REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only   OFF
unique_checks                ON
updatable_views_with_limit   YES
validate_password_check_user_name          OFF
validate_password_dictionary_file
validate_password_length     8
validate_password_mixed_case_count         1
validate_password_number_count             1
validate_password_policy     MEDIUM
validate_password_special_char_count       1
version        5.7.17
version_comment              Source distribution
version_compile_machine      x86_64
version_compile_os           osx10.12
wait_timeout   28800
```

UPDATE 2/15: I doubled wait_timeout to 57600 and connect_timeout to 20 this morning based on some feedback found in other threads.  Should I also increase interactive_timeout? Are there any negative effects I should watch out for as a result of such changes?

Comment: "web site errors while trying to connect to the db" What type of error did you get ? There is a code/msg with those errors ?

Comment: I think, mysql_* function is used. It's deprecated in php7

Comment: MAMP as in "Mac Apache MySQL PHP", installed from source code using MacPorts.  Hardware is a Mac with 16 gigs RAM.

Comment: @e-Learner The errors typically displayed in the browser are a default error from WordPress: "Error connecting to database".   The command line error I most recently saw was: `Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102 when trying to connect`

Comment: @TamilSelvanC, I'm not sure where you're referring to the mysql_* function being used.  In WordPress or a plugin?  More details about where to find and fix, please!